# Node unable to connect to the constellation node (quorum)

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

Looking at the 7Node example from:
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/7nodes

and trying to configure my network but have ran into a lot of trouble over the days, trying to get geth to take quorum options or the --permissioned flag having errors in a geth release, trying to rebuild etc. I am frustrated and I am weak. The documentation isn't that great. And it does not tell you how the constellation node and your geth node should interact. I looked at the scripts and I tried but I am not getting anywhere. I only got this far in 3 days.

CONFIG:

```
Geth: 1.7.2-stable-d4a1b095

go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64

Constellation Node 0.3.2
```

start constellation node:

```
nohup constellation-node --url=https://127.0.0.1:9001/ --port=9001 --workdir=qdata/c1 --socket=tm.ipc --publickeys=tm.pub --privatekeys=tm.key --othernodes=https://127.0.0.1:9001/ 2> const1.log
```

nohup.out:

```
Unlocking tm.key
Unlocked tm.key
```

const1.log:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
16:47:16 [INFO] Log level is LevelWarn
16:47:16 [WARN] tls-server-cert.pem's hostname (127.0.0.) is different from the one given in the configuration (127.0.0.1). This may cause connection problems.
16:47:16 [WARN] tls-client-cert.pem's hostname (127.0.0.) is different from the one given in the configuration (127.0.0.1). This may cause connection problems.
```

script used to generate:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
set -e

echo "[*] Starting Ethereum nodes"
set -v
ARGS="--nodiscover --raft --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum --emitcheckpoints"
PRIVATE_CONFIG=qdata/c1/tm.ipc nohup geth --datadir qdata/dd1 $ARGS --permissioned --raftport 50401 --rpcport 22000 --port 21000 2>>qdata/logs/1.log &
```

1.log:

```
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
    panic: MustNew: Failed to connect to Constellation (qdata/c1/tm.ipc): Get http+unix://c/upcheck: read unix @->tm.ipc: i/o timeout

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/constellation.MustNew(0xc42001400f, 0xf, 0xc42001400f)
            /home/ubuntu/quorum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/constellation/constellation.go:75 +0x18d
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private.FromEnvironmentOrNil(0x1054ac3, 0xe, 0xc4201bd3a0, 0xc4201bd380)
            /home/ubuntu/quorum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/private.go:19 +0x6e
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private.init()
            /home/ubuntu/quorum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/private.go:22 +0x69
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.init()
            <autogenerated>:1 +0x104
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/utils.init()
            <autogenerated>:1 +0x6e
    main.init()
            <autogenerated>:1 +0x6a
```

Node static-node.gensis:

```
["enode://60b56f0bda5047ccb7cc1d18f828da62eb0d13241b213e5ee04e88d8fbfc145da98de8e019faab9a6d76124b92d07b0e92b084137a396b2cf72334024cc1c6dc@[::]:21000?raftport=50401",
"enode://2d34e98237a26e5e1f56ce8909e946df66476b57c8239f9db310de058fe08afc8ea2f40b979830ccf94207a7069175ae2ad1777a9fe2f5683fda2d04c25963d2@[::]:21001??raftport=50402",
"enode://5cda3acad3eb4be84c05d33b973886f152678386c65290281d59f19ff18ee5a7fe95626d47dc909dcb9c3ede1273aa6ff47b03a4d758ba68d02a4b4996e34fa3@[::]:21002??raftport=50403"]
```

gensis.json

```
{
  "alloc": {},
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "config": {
    "byzantiumBlock": 1,
    "chainId": 1,
    "eip150Block": 1,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip158Block": 1,
    "isQuorum":true
  },
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to delete the certificates, know hosts and keys generated by constellation previously in this folder **workdir=qdata/c1**. These certificates are used for communication between constellation nodes, for this reason it is important that these certificates are well generated.
- The option **--othernodes = https://127.0.0.1:9001/** in your constellation execution command is trying to connect itself. If you want to connect to a second node of constellation, you need to place the ip of the second node with the specific port.
- After, the GETH error you are getting is because the node Constellation is not running. Geth needs Constellation to be running in order to start up.
- Finally execute the following command considering the option othernodes as I commented previously.

  nohup constellation-node --url=https://127.0.0.1:9001/ --port=9001
  --workdir=qdata/c1 --socket=tm.ipc --publickeys=tm.pub --privatekeys=tm.key **--               othernodes=https://127.0.0.1:9001/** 2> const1.log